# How can I change the child of a container via Dart code?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to dynamically set the child widget of a specific container using Dart code, specifically on a button press. Where should I start to accomplish this? I've already explored using a PageView, but that's not really what I'm looking for.

If I were web developing, I would easily be able to edit an element via its ID. Is there a Flutter equivalent of HTML ID's? Controllers seem limiting here.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter doesn't really work that way. Flutter, like React, is a declarative environment as opposed to an imperative environment. Widget trees are built from state, and as such, a widget higher in the tree doesn't know, or even care, about its children.

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/declarative

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/web-devs

Comment: Thanks, that clears some stuff up. In that case - what are my options in terms of achieving something like this?

It must be possible because I've definitely seen and used apps that have a persistent navigation bar.

Comment: You need to plan out where your state lives in the hierarchy. You can "drill" state down into the tree by passing it to children or you can "reach up" into state via the `BuildContext` using `InheritedWidget`s and a whole lot of other neat tools like `Provider`. Try going through this example. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget _dynamicWidget = FlutterLogo();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _dynamicWidget,
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _dynamicWidget = Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                    );
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Change')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```